# .htaccss Rewrite Rules

Tags: html, .htaccess, directory-structure

I currently have a folder structure of

root/page1.html

root/page2.html

root/page3.html

root/page3/subpage1.html

and am trying to use the rewrite rules to hide the .html part when displayed in brower.

Currently .htaccess looks like:

```
#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex home.html

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

The issue I'm having is when I try to click a link that would bring me to root/page3.html its 404ing because it is trying to redirect to  root/page3/.html

What is the best way to solve this? Should I be using .htaccess for this or change my structure?

Answer (score 0):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: So its now trying to access root/page3/ as a directory it looks like, not the html page itself.

Comment: Comes up looking like a directory webpage, I've edited my original post to include the full .htaccess code

Comment: What is URL you see in browser and what exactly is the error?

Comment: with the current .htaccess I have the url is reading mywebsite.com/artists/

It is not erroring because that is still a directory with several .html pages, but what I was hoping to accomplish was have it be mywebsite.com/artists.html while hiding the .html part of the URL.

Comment: You have given examples of `page1`, `page2` etc in question and no where it is mentioned that your `html` filename is same as a directory name. First test this rule with only a valid `.html` file present in site root and see if that works or not. If that also doesn't work then edit your question with your complete ,htaccess

Comment: My apologies I should have clarified. The rule does work, my issue does indeed stem from the fact that there is a directory and an html page of the same name.

Is this something that can't be done? 

Also the complete .htaccess is listed in the original post. That's all I have in it currently.

Comment: Does `artists/` have another .htaccess inside? Also does it have `artists/home.html` ?

Comment: It does not have a .htaccess inside nor a home or index.html. It does have several html pages (artist1.html, artist2.html etc.)

Comment: Try adding `DirectorySlash off` at top and retest.